# Sharepoint's clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync() doesn't come back

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint-2010

Here is the code I'm using to retrieve the current username from SharePoint 2010 via Silverlight:

```
ClientContext clientContext = ClientContext.Current;
if (clientContext == null)
{
    SharepointUser = "[Unknown]";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Beginning server query now...");
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, s => s.CurrentUser);
    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync((s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RESPONSE!");
        SharepointUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        MessageBox.Show("Hello, " + SharepointUser + "!");
    },
    (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.ToString());
    });
}
```

The problem is that the request never comes back! The success/error events don't trigger at all, and the request just seems like it's going into the void.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use Fiddler to observe the HTTP conversation with the server.  http://www.fiddler2.com/

Comment: It doesn't even show up as being requested through my computer with Fiddler. If the silverlight app is hosted on the server, and it tries to request information from the sharepoint server, why would the traffic go through my local computer?

Comment: Your code is client-side code, not server-side.

Comment: Fair enough, but that doesn't explain why the request is never made. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageBox.Show is probably the cause of the issue. I was having the same issue and by debugging I found that the calls the MessageBox.Show within the ExecuteQueryAsync callbacks were throwing an exception "Invalid cross-thread access". I needed to wrap the calls like this to get it to work:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Request Suceeded"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
ClientContext clientContext = ClientContext.Current;
if (clientContext == null)
{
    SharepointUser = "[Unknown]";
}
else
{
            try
            {
    MessageBox.Show("Beginning server query now...");
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, s => s.CurrentUser);
    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync((s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RESPONSE!");
        SharepointUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        MessageBox.Show("Hello, " + SharepointUser + "!");
    },
    (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.ToString());
    });
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Synchronous error occurred: " + err.ToString());
            }
}
```

If an attempt to start an asynchronous operation fails it usualy throws an error synchronously rather than leaving it to the asynchronous callback.

Comment: But you see the "Beginning..." message?